# Update a table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column `Table1.Tradedate` and another column `Table2.SettlementDate`.
Based on the comparison between these 2, I want to update a column in table 2

```
IF (Table1.TradeDate <= Table2.SettlementDate)
BEGIN
UPDATE Table2 SET Status='Y'
END
```

This is what I have tried but I know its wrong, since the table will obviously contain more than 1 records. So, I believe what I should do is

1. use a join on 2 tables based on some `@id` to pick a particular record
2. check the IF condition for that particular record
3. update the `Status` column in `table2`.

I hope my approach is correct but I am writing it incorrectly.

Table1:

```
SKacc | Name | TradeDate   | Othercolumns....
1     | xxx  |  01/07/2019 |
2     | xxx  |  01/06/2019 |
```

Table2:

```
SKAcc | Name | SettlementDate | Status |Other Columns....
1     | xxx  |  01/08/2019    | NULL   |
2     | xxx  |  01/08/2019    | NULL   |
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results will greatly help here. I suspect you're after a `JOIN`, but we don't know the relationship between your tables here.

Comment: Provide your sample data @geek

Comment: @Mansoor thanks for replying. I have updated the question. There are only 2 tables, so basically I can join them

Comment: @Larnu yes, I am looking for a join. Both tables have a same field, SKAcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend a `JOIN` for this purpose.  Instead:

```
update table2
    set Status = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id = t2.id and
                        t1.tradeDate <= t2.settlementDate
                 );
```

The reason I recommend this version is because you have not specified that `id` is unique in `table1`.  In general, you only want to use `JOIN` in `UPDATE` when you can guarantee that there is only one matching row.

Answer (score 3):

Try below

```
update t2 set Status = 'Y'
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.tradeDate <= t2.settlementDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Try joining the two tables with the related column and then update the table you want to update with the value. Using inner join in the example but can change depending on the usecase

```
UPDATE Table2 
  SET Status = 'Y'
  FROM Table2
  INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.id = Table2.table1_id
  WHERE Table1.TradeDate <= Table2.SettlementDate
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833694/6426692)?